# Change text of a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a quick question about listView's and how check if a ListView (which contains null items) has a certain string?

Here is the code which add to sepcific items (under column 5 in the listView). It basically checks if that item appears in Google search or not. If it does, it'll write yes to that specific row, if not it'll leave it blank:

```
string google2 = http.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + textBox1.Text + "");
                string[] embedid = getBetweenAll(vid, "type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>");

                for (int i = 0; i < embedid.Length; i++)
                {

                    if (google2.Contains(embedid[i]))
                    {
                        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Yes");
                        }
                    }
```

Now what I am trying to do is check if that certain column contains items that say Yes. If it does color them Green if not don't.

Here's the code for that:

```
 if (i.SubItems[5].Text.Contains("Yes"))
                        {
                            labelContainsVideo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        }
```

My issue is I keep getting an error that says `InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.`

My hunch is that there are null items in column 5 which might be messing it up but I dont know.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Item to see if the SubItem Collection has the correct Number of values.

i.e.

```
int threshold = 5;

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems.Count > threshold)
    {
        if (item.SubItems[5].Text.Contains("Yes"))
        {
            // Do your work here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

Do you think if we cycle through column 5 and if it doesnt contain the video instead of leaving it blank we put a space or something then when we're checking if it contains yes or not, we replace it?

Comment: @EdwinTorres how many subitems do you have, I was operating under the idea( obviously false) that you had no more than 5 subitems

Comment: I have only 5 columns, I need all of this to go in column 5. In that column the amount of sub items depends how many videos appear on Google search. If a video appears on Google then it'll display Yes in that row. How many 'Yes's appear depends. This can vary from as little to 1 or 5, etc.

Comment: @EdwinTorres You are still getting an error with the code that I gave? I am checking that you actually have 5 columns before I set the index.

Comment: @EdwinTorres what is your threshold set to? be aware the item itself is at index position 0

Comment: Sweet! I just tested the new code you edited it too, I didnt realize you had an int value at the top and it worked! :)

Comment: @EdwinTorres Glad to be of Help

Comment: @EdwinTorres You are welcome, sometimes another pair of eyes helps